# Addthis Widget not working on firefox and Chrome

Tags: widget, addthis

I am using AddThis widget on a web app am developing. The widget is showing up on IE but not on other browsers.

Link to the app is here:
http://122.160.201.90/training/po/widget.html

If you check the link in IE, it shows the AddThis button but not on other browsers. Could someone please help me in fixing this issue!

Below is the code I am using to add AddThis widget:

`$('#top_menu').append('<a class="addthis_button_compact at300m" style="font-size:14px;color:grey;margin-top:32px;margin-left:224px;position:absolute;z-index:3">SHARE</a><scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');`

Works fine on IE but not on other browsers.